# How can I complete get request then continue execution

Tags: angular, typescript, httprequest

My `get request` is not getting finished but execution of code is continuous. Consequently the the dependent variables are not getting initialized.

I am making `get request` as below

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,private objdataService: dataService) { }
  loginsAllRecords:any=[];
  
  //this is calling on button click
  onSubmit(form) {
    this.loadLogins();
    this.validate_user(form.value.name,form.value.password)
  }

  validate_user(username, pin)
  {
    var isEmail;
    var isPassword;

    //this is empty but after execution successfull console.log("data in load ", this.loginsAllRecords) returns data
    console.log(this.loginsAllRecords)
    var email = Object.values(this.loginsAllRecords).filter(x => x.email ==username)
    var password = Object.values(this.loginsAllRecords).filter(x => x.pin ==pin)
  }

  
  async loadLogins() {
     return await this.objdataService.getLogins_service().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.loginsAllRecords = data;
      console.log("data in load ", this.loginsAllRecords)
    })
  }

}
```

In above code `onSubmit` getting called first and `this.loginsAllRecords` supposed to initialized. Then calling `validate_user()` but `this.loginsAllRecords` null in `validate_user()`. After program execution finished, `this.loginsAllRecords` getting values and logging the data in console.

This is service class

```
export class dataService {


  public httpOptions : any;
  loginsAllRecords:any=[];

  public loginUrl="http://localhost:3000/logins";
  constructor(private _http : HttpClient) {
    this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders(
          { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          }) 
      }
  }

    getLogins_service(): Observable<login> {
    return this._http.get<login>(this.loginUrl)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }  

    // Error handling 
    handleError(error) {
      let errorMessage = '';
      if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
        // Get client-side error
        errorMessage = error.error.message;
      } else {
        // Get server-side error
        errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
      }
      window.alert(errorMessage);
      return throwError(errorMessage);
   }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I guess you are mixing `async` `await` with observables ... any specific reason to use async await ?

Comment: async/await work with promises. They will only work if the async function your are awaiting returns a Promise.

Comment: @user1608841 - I was getting this error. I did google they suggested `async` `await`, I added.Still same issue. Without these markers also facing same issue.

Comment: let me add piece of code as answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

async/await work with promises. They will only work if the async function your are awaiting returns a Promise (not observable) so subscribe wont work here.

```
async loadLogins() {
    const data= await this.objdataService.getLogins_service().toPromise();
    this.loginsAllRecords = data;
  }
```

Another approach using Observable :

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,private objdataService: dataService) { }
  loginsAllRecords:any=[];
  
  //this is calling on button click
  onSubmit(form) {
    this.loadLogins(form);
    
  }

  validate_user(username, pin)
  {
    var isEmail;
    var isPassword;

    //this is empty but after execution successfull console.log("data in load ", this.loginsAllRecords) returns data
    console.log(this.loginsAllRecords)
    var email = Object.values(this.loginsAllRecords).filter(x => x.email ==username)
    var password = Object.values(this.loginsAllRecords).filter(x => x.pin ==pin)
  }

  
   loadLogins(form) {
     this.objdataService.getLogins_service().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      this.loginsAllRecords = data;
      this.validate_user(form.value.name,form.value.password)
      console.log("data in load ", this.loginsAllRecords)
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: what error you are getting ? any error in console ?

Comment: try Observable approach

Comment: Sorry to bother you bro.. I have just used `loadLogins(form)` method in registration page so that I can check if email already exist or not, just removed `this.validate_user` line. Faced the same issue, method is not completing and control moving ahead. Can you suggest

Comment: `loadLogin(form)` method is using http call which is asynchronous. So once http req fulfills then only loginAllRecords will be available hence I added validate_user method inside subscription

Answer (score 1):

Check **Finalize** in **rxjs** operators Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable, but will call a specified function when the source terminates on complete or error.

```
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';



loadLogins() {
         return this.objdataService.getLogins_service().pipe(
            finalize(() =>  {
             console.log("Done");
             // write your code here
             })
            ).subscribe((data: {}) => {
          this.loginsAllRecords = data;
          console.log("data in load ", this.loginsAllRecords)
        })
      }
```

Code inside the finalize will be executed when the source terminates on complete or error.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do handle it simply in html part, you can simply use a variable of type boolean inside the subscription part, and use the structural directive in the html part.

Example:

```
public loadStuff: boolean = false;
return await this.objdataService.getLogins_service().subscribe((data: {}) => {
   this.loadStuff = true;
})
```

In HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="loadStuff">
  ...
</div>
```